# Xcode not respecting the constraints on my iphone xib file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xib, autolayout

I am having problems figuring out why Xcode is not respecting the constraints on my iphone xib file.

This is how I set a button in the xib file:

and this is how it appears in the simulator:

[image: xib file configuration]

and this is how it appears in the simulator:

[image: simulator image]

I defined the size of the button:
[image]

Any of you know what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the button to stay at the center of the view, you just need two constraints.

- vertically center in container
- horizontally center in container

Add this two and get rid of the vertical space containers.

Comment: I have define the size of the button. I add image where I define the size of the button

Comment: it's not clear from the question where you want the button to be and where actually is.

Comment: I want the button to be in the center of the view

Comment: forgive me for being harsh, but if you show a screenshot where the bounds of the superview are not visible, how the hell is anybody supposed to infer that? Anyway I'm gonna update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don`t no much about constraint but u can remove it with Doing uncheck in AutoLayout in property editor.

And than palce your button and make it center horizontal and center vertical from property editor of xib.

And make all bounds pack in AutoSizing given in property editor.

Comment: "Turn off Autolayout" is not an answer to "how can I get Autolayout to work?"

Comment: I never said this this is the answer i gave an alternate way to it